# Memory footprint of arrow functions and bind

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, profiling

I am trying to profile memory usage of arrow functions and `bind` to see if there is a difference. I would like to know how to proceed from where I got so far.

First, I wrote two javascript files, one using arrow functions and another `bind`. I then took a heap snapshot.

**bind.js**

```
var heapdump = require('heapdump');

var arr = [];
this.value = 'foo';

for (var i = 0; i < 100000; ++i) {
  arr.push(
    (function() {
      console.log(this.value);
    }.bind(this))
  );
}

heapdump.writeSnapshot('./bind.heapsnapshot')

console.log(arr.length);
```

**arrow.js**

```
var heapdump = require('heapdump');

var arr = [];
this.value = 'foo';

for (var i = 0; i < 100000; ++i) {
  arr.push(
    (() => {
      console.log(this.value);
    })
  );
}

heapdump.writeSnapshot('./arrow.heapsnapshot')

console.log(arr.length);
```

Using Chrome devtool's profile tab, I can see the comparison between two snapshots:

[image: heap-snapshot]

I would like to know how I can interpret the result.

Concretely, what does it mean:

- that the size of one heapdump is four times the size of another?
- to have such `#delta` and `size_delta` values?
- to have so much delta for `(string)`?